# Java String from byte array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am currently reading in a UDP byte array that I know is a string and I know the MAXIMUM possible length of said string. So I print out a string (which is usually shorter than the max length). I am able to print it out but it prints out the text then junk characters. Is there a way to trim the junk binary data without knowing the actual length of the valid text?

```
String result = new String(input, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
```

Ill try for those asking for more data. Here is how the UDP message is read:

```
sock.receive(incoming);
byte[] data = incoming.getData();
String s = new String(data, 0, incoming.getLength());
```

The UDP message itself will contain a header of fixed size and then a set of data (Max size of 1024 bytes). This data may be int, string, byte etc. This is determined by header data. So depending on the type, i chop the data out based on the appropriate size chunks. The problem I am focusing on is the String type of data. I know that the max size of a string will be 128 bytes per string, so I read that amount in chunks via where dataArray is the byte array.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i = i + readSize)
    {
        dataArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(msg, i, i + readSize);
    }
```

Then I use the original code in the first code set in this post to place the data into a string object. Thing is, the text that is usually sent is less than the 128 bytes allocated for max size. So when I print the string, I get the valid text and then whitespace and non-normal ascii characters (junk data). Hope this addition helps.

An example of the output is here. Everything up to the .mof is valid:

https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ai0t7Oj1PUFBpRP9K_2RlocAK4B7

Comment: We need more details to help you

Comment: pls, show us the code where you read the UDP stream

Comment: Please post an example output...

Comment: Sounds like you are not using the correct Charset, the decoder of the input string.

Comment: You need to tell us the encoding of the string.  Many encodings use more than one byte to represent a character.

Comment: The source is one of our corporate systems, which I know the charset is ASCII.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok here is how I was able to get it to work. It's a rather manual method but before using

```
String result = new String(input, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
```

to combine the byte array into a string, I looked at each byte and made sure it was within the printable range of 0x20 - 0x7e. If not, I replaced the value with a space (0x20). Then finished off with a .trim on the string.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to trim the junk binary data without knowing the actual
>   length of the valid text?

Yes you can simply call [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--), it will remove the trailing [**null characters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). Indeed `trim()` removes every leading and trailing characters less or equal to `\u0020` (aka whitespace) which includes `\u0000` (aka null character).

```
byte[] bytes = "foo bar".getBytes();

// Simulate message with a size bigger than the actual encoded String
byte[] msg = new byte[32];
System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, msg, 0, bytes.length);

// Decode the message
String result = new String(msg, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
// Trim the result
System.out.printf("Result: '%s'%n", result.trim());
```

**Output:**

```
Result: 'foo bar'
```

Comment: It's not just whitespace.

Comment: No. I'll give it a shot though. But from the Java API: trim()
Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

Comment: No you misunderstand the doc, trim removes every character before `\u0020` which includes the null character `\u0000`

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot. Unfortunately I am at the mercy of a coworker who is running the system and typically does not have string values coming over the line.

Comment: Ok I tried trim and it didn't work. Here was the output. Can't copy and paste because the junk characters don't show. The good info is everything before the .mof file. https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ai0t7Oj1PUFBpRP9K_2RlocAK4B7

Comment: those characters are not ascii neither null characters